# Displaying mysql fetched results into row-wise organized table by entry fields?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've a mysql table named `product` with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id int(6) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    image varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
    link varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
    price decimal(3,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and I would like to visualize the retrieved results `{product1,...,product5}` into a html/php table of 3 columns with also the following structure:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
    <tr>
       <td>product1.image</td>   <td>product2.image</td>   <td>product3.image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>product1.name</td>    <td>product2.name</td>    <td>product3.name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>product1.link</td>    <td>product2.link</td>    <td>product3.link</td>
    </tr>

    <tr> 
         <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td>product4.image</td>   <td>product5.image</td>  <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>product4.name</td>   <td>product5.name</td>  <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>product4.link</td>   <td>product5.link</td>  <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note that the fields of a given entry (e.g. `product1.{image,description,link}`) are displayed in different rows.
The code below illustrates how do the images of some products could be displayed.

```
$table = 'product';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, image, description, link FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2' width='100%'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td> <img src="$field->image" border="0"></td>";

    if($i%3==0){echo"</tr><tr>";}
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: We need to know the exact table structure, and your current PHP code that displays the data.

Comment: So you want an html structure, which always displays three products next to each other, and for each product places the image above the description which is above the link?

Comment: @RafaelCichocki, exactly

Comment: @Jocelyn, updated my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want an html structure, which always displays three products next to each other, and for each product places the image above the description which is above the link.

... and I wouldn't use a table for it.

I'm assuming you know how to [fetch data from a database](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp).
You loop through the result table and the display as you need it:

```
$counter = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<span><div>".$row["image"]."</div><div>".$row["description"]."</div><div>".$row["link"]."</div></span>;
    $counter += 1;
    if($counter % 3 = 0)
    {
        echo "</br>
    }
}
```

This gives you a set of 3  elements next to each other, and within them 3 div elements above each other, each containing a detail about your product.

Here's the code for using a surrounding table:

```
echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2' width='100%'><tr>";
$counter = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<td><div>".$row["image"]."</div><div>".$row["description"]."</div><div>".$row["link"]."</div></td>;
    $counter += 1;
    if($counter % 3 = 0)
    {
        $echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

... and here's as you requested in your question:

```
echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2' width='100%'>";
$counter = 1;
$htmlHolder1 = "<tr>";
$htmlHolder2 = "<tr>";
$htmlHolder3 = "<tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $htmlHolder1 .= "<td>".$row["image"]."</td>";
    $htmlHolder2 .= "<td>".$row["description"]."</td>";
    $htmlHolder3 .= "<td>".$row["link"]."</td>";
    $counter += 1;
    if($counter % 3 = 0)
    {
        echo $htmlHolder1."</tr>";
        echo $htmlHolder2."</tr>";
        echo $htmlHolder3."</tr>";

        $htmlHolder1 = "<tr>";
        $htmlHolder2 = "<tr>";
        $htmlHolder3 = "<tr>";
    }
}
if($counter % 3 != 0)
{
    echo $htmlHolder1."</tr>";
    echo $htmlHolder2."</tr>";
    echo $htmlHolder3."</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I would only use a table if my data really is organised by the displayed rows, otherwise any future manipulation becomes an extra hassle.

Comment: so, the `<span></span>` creates a sort of `block`, and the `<div>` correspond to the elements, right? Why you would not go for `<table>`?

Comment: my data is actually organised. do you mind in illustration also a solution using `<table>`?

Comment: thanks for the second illustration, but what about a `not` surrounding table, but a normal one, as the one depicted in my example.

Comment: The solution you want, as you have posted in your question, requires that you reorganize your data first, and then create your table.

Comment: @Tin updated the answer - the lowest code sample does what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A loop to build the cells, counting each one as you go, then every XX (third using your example) you close the row and open a new one.

Not sure if you need more or not but that is the basics.

Comment: i think, what you have proposed does not solve what i'm looking for. it is what i'm already doing. See my post.